# Is it feasible to use crypto.subtle.digest to generate a digest of the given file?

Tags: javascript

I've run this example that comes from [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest)

```
const text = 'An obscure body in the S-K System, your majesty. The inhabitants refer to it as the planet Earth.';

async function digestMessage(message) {
  const msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(message);                           // encode as (utf-8) Uint8Array
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgUint8);           // hash the message
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));                     // convert buffer to byte array
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''); // convert bytes to hex string
  return hashHex;
}

const digestHex = await digestMessage(text);
console.log(digestHex);
```

I understand the basic usage shown in the example.

However, I don't know how to generates a digest of the given file/blob. I've tried this

```
const hashBuffer = crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', file);
```

click https://jsfiddle.net/5dn4bjfw/ to see full version.

and got this error.

```
The provided value is not of type '(ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView)'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crypto.subtle.digest()` [requires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) an ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView.

[File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) can be viewed as ArrayBuffer via `file.arrayBuffer()`.

The function in the example above should be [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) as in [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) and use `await` for all the calls that return Promises.

```
async function myFunction(){
  const finput = document.getElementById('fileinput');
  const file = finput.files[0];
  const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', arrayBuffer); // hash the message
  console.log(hashBuffer);
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)); // convert buffer to byte array
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
  console.log(hashHex);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work. Would the hashHex map change if it was `sha-1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an `ArrayBuffer`, you might able to use the `arrayBuffer` API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer

```
    blob.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => {
      //your encoding functions here, pass buffer to the function
   });
```